# sql if statment syntax help please

Tags: php, sql

```
    <?php 
include 'dbc.php';

?>
 <?php session_start();
 $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
 //$update = Reminder1;
// $rt1 = Reminder1;
// $mm1 = Reminder1;


 mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT reminder FROM users WHERE $id = id)") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 

if EXISTS (reminder == Reminder1)') {
echo("Update Your Pasword reset reminder page");
}
else {
echo("redirect to /home.php");
}


?>
```

can anyone help me out on why this is failing, would be great i have been working on this for a while and it feels like i am hitting brick walls lol. i am still in testing so the to echos will be edited soon as it is in working condition so ignore them lines for now i left it all in for examples sake.

Comment: It looks to me that you need to do some more reading into PHP syntax as there's quite a few issues there. Also, MySQL connections through PHP almost always use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) these days, rather than the old mysql_ functions. There are various security reasons for this.

Comment: seems lots of issue in your post you did the mistakes in if condition and many more.

Comment: $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE $id = id")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

sorry i got it displaying but need doble checking

//if (reminder == Reminder1 | | $special_key =='SK12345') {


if ('reminder == $reminder') {
echo("Update Your Pasword reset reminder page");
}
else {
echo("redirect to /home.php");
}


?>

Comment: why is it wrong remember i need help, not un constructed criticism :D be more specific i have correct syntax issue best i can and got rd of error but see above message to see update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetch data

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT reminder FROM users WHERE id='".$id."' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);

if($row['reminder'] == 'Reminder1') {
    header("Location: /reset_password.php");
}
else {
    header("Location: /home.php");
}


// but you should use PDO
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'user', 'pass');
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT reminder FROM users WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1");
$sth->execute(array(':id' => $id));
$sth->setAttribute(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row = $sth->fetch();

if($row['reminder'] == 'Reminder1') {
    header("Location: /reset_password.php");
}
else {
    header("Location: /home.php");
}
```

Comment: yes that last one with your layout worked perfectly once i removed my old code :d thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

[**`Why is the MySQL extension (ext/mysql) discouraged from use?`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated)

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$DB = new PDO('mysql:dbname=database;host=localhost', 'user', 'pass');
$stmt = $DB->prepare('SELECT reminder FROM users WHERE id = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($id));
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($result == 'Reminder1') {
    echo 'Update Your Pasword reset reminder page';
} else {
    header('Location: /home.php');
}
?>
```

Also see:

- [control
  structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php)
- [`if` control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)
- [header() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)